# Getting Attribute from Table Cell into Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm generating an HTML table which contains rows like this one: I've been able to successfully get the ID and the trackingNumber value, but I'm trying to get the data-categoryName-id value and I'm stumped. Here's my script:

```js
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
  var recid = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
  var trackingNumber = $(this).val();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<tr id="53462365">
  <td>JB44566</td>
  <td>SKU123</td>
  <td>CARTON PAPER A4</td>
  <td>PAPER</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>966257111</td>
  <td></td>
  <td id="53462365"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tracking #" name="trackingNumber" data-categoryName-id="Office Supplies" autocomplete="off" value=""></td>
  <td id="53462365"><input type="number" id="53462365" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ID Tag" name="idTag" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

Trying to add another like, e.g.:

```
var categoryName =
```

that returns the value for the data-categoryName-id for the current row but completely stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.attr()`

```js
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
  var recid = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
  var trackingNumber = $(this).val();
  var categoryName = $(this).attr('data-categoryName-id');
  console.log(categoryName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<tr id="53462365">
  <td>JB44566</td>
  <td>SKU123</td>
  <td>CARTON PAPER A4</td>
  <td>PAPER</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>966257111</td>
  <td></td>
  <td id="53462365"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tracking #" name="trackingNumber" data-categoryName-id="Office Supplies" autocomplete="off" value=""></td>
  <td id="53462365"><input type="number" id="53462365" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ID Tag" name="idTag" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method that allows you to get or set `data-*` attributes:

```
var categoryName = $(this).data('categoryName-id');
```